# Servermanager isnt supported in IIS 8 and above

Tags: c#, application-pool, servermanager

I want to check wheather an application pool is present or not in IIS.For that I use servermanager as follows-->

```
ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();
  if (mgr.ApplicationPools["myapplicationpoolname"] == null)
{
//My Procedure to create application pool as app pool doesnt exist
}
```

This works buttery smooth on IIS 7.5 and below versions.But in IIS 8 and above servermanager cannot be used the above way due to memory leak issues.I even tried the suggested workaround on MSDN as follows-->

```
 var mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote("localhost");
```

Still no luck.I am stuck up as I am unable to use servermanager in IIS 8 and above:(Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: I finally solved my problem using appcmd.exe arguments :)..Theres no other option probably :)

Answer (score 0):

ServerManager should work just fine in Windows 8 or above, please make sure you are referencing the right version of it located in Windows\system32\inetsrv. Also make sure that you are not "copying a version of the DLL", this DLL should always be loaded from the GAC and references from inetsrv directory, otherwise you can run into versioning issues.

Comment: Mate Windows 8 or above comes with embedded IIS 8.5 which doesnt support servermanager class due to memory leak issues.Have a check on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting that information, but ServerManager is absolutely supported in Windows 8.1, and Windows 10. It is the official way to use Managed code to manage IIS configuration (I know first hand), and if you are running into a memory leak I think the best thing is to call us and we can help you figure it out. Feel free to reach out to me if that is the case and I can help look at it. If you are disposing, things should be reclaimed eventually.